# Tomcat Server fails to start in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I work in eclipse but it shows a error message "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

and the server fails and the application not run.
I also delete temp file from C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core
but still the problem have been not resloved...

Comment: Have you see any error in the console when you are trying to start Tomcat ?

Comment: Aug 11, 2015 6:53:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 11, 2015 6:53:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Aug 11, 2015 6:53:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Comment: it shows the above msg

Comment: ya it displays lot of msg on console..

Comment: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FirstPro]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it helps to remove .snap file located in the directory : `<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`

Comment: i delete it too. but it doesn't help me.

Comment: add full stacktrace to your question plz